# Create Fibonacci Sequence in Prolog with 1 Parameter

Tags: prolog, fibonacci

I am a beginner on prolog and is trying to create fibonacci sequence rules. But it can't run because of error in the code called arithmetic fib is not a function.

Source for my code :

```
fib(N):-
    N<1, S is 0,
    N<2, S is 1,
    N1 is fib(N-1),
    N2 is fib(N-2),
    S is N1 + N2,
    write(S, " ").
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You know Prolog is a *logical* programming language. Meaning a *predicate* either succeeds or fails, it does **not** return a value.

Comment: Also, you cannot re-assign variables in Prolog. They are instantiated and can only be done so once in the execution of a predicate clause unless backtracking occurs due to failure. So, for example, if `N < 1` succeeds, then `S is 0` will instantiate `S` with the arithmetic evaluation of `0`, then `N < 2` will succeed and then `S is 1` will fail since `S` is instantiated with `0` and `0 is 1` is false. You need to read a Prolog tutorial or basic text book and learn a little about Prolog before writing your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fib(0,0).
fib(1,1).

fib(N,R):- N>1,
           N1 is N-1,
           N2 is N-2,
           fib(N1,R1),
           fib(N2,R2),
           R is R1+R2.
```

This how fibonacci can be defined using prolog, I defined the two base cases where the element n0 is 0 and element n1 is 1

and then I identified any other element that is not equal to 0 or 1 to be Fn-1 + Fn-2

to call the predicate you simply

```
?- fib(6,X).
```

where you expect X to have the result

the result this case will be

```
X = 8
```

Comment: You really should use `N > 1`, not `N \= 0, N \= 1`. Otherwise, `fib(-1, X)` overflows the stack and won't simply fail.